# Efficiently Update MySQL Records

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-update

Example Data:

```
PostID                DateTime            DataTimeProper UserID   UserName IPAddress
1234567.page#00008912 07/25/2013 14:50:21 NULL           00000001 TestUser 127.0.0.1
2468012.page#04208002 07/28/2013 18:42:13 NULL           03209827 BobTest  127.0.0.2
```

I'm looking for the most efficient way to update every record in a table (millions) where the `DateTimeProper` column IS `NULL` with the value being inserted coming from a `str_to_date` of the DateTime column.

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`DateTime`,'%m/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: so your `DateTime` column is of type string? It would be more efficient to use MySQL's `DATETIME` type. That would also make your query for updating `DateTimeProper` more efficient and quicker.

Comment: @mavili thanks for the tip, the type has been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply

```
UPDATE yourTable SET DateTimeProper = STR_TO_DATE(`DateTime`,'%m/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')
WHERE DateTimeProper IS NULL;
```

It takes as long as it takes and it's a one time operation anyway, right?

If you really insist, you can make yourself the trouble to update in chunks, like (assuming you have an auto_increment column named id or something)

```
UPDATE yourTable SET DateTimeProper = STR_TO_DATE(`DateTime`,'%m/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')
WHERE DateTimeProper IS NULL
AND id BETWEEN 0 AND 10000;
```

and then

```
UPDATE yourTable SET DateTimeProper = STR_TO_DATE(`DateTime`,'%m/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')
WHERE DateTimeProper IS NULL
AND id BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000;
```

and so on. Some people do that in the hope, that the chunks fit into memory, but in my opinion it's not worth the trouble. MySQL already does a good job at that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE table SET DataTimeProper = 
    (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DateTime,'%m/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s'))
WHERE DataTimeProper IS NULL
```

Although you should consider changing your `DateTime` column to be of type `DATETIME` instead of string, as this will make it more efficient. Especially as you're dealing with tables of multi-million rows.

Comment: I'd guess he wants to do this operation to convert the column to datetime. Simply altering doesn't work, so it's nonsense what you suggest here. Also your update statement doesn't work. This subselect, from where is it getting the DateTime column? And how do you relate it to the row of the update statement?

Comment: have you actually tried running that query on a MySQL command line or somewhere before claiming my "update statement doesn't work"? I have run it and it does run OK.

Comment: and to answer: it gets it from the current row of data that's updating the value for. so it *is* what the user wants!

Comment: Maybe it works, still it's nonsense to have a subselect. See my query, that's the way to do it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'nonsense' but rather 'unnecessary'.

Comment: Okay, call it unnecessary. I'm no native speaker.